# Double slashes in paths in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Here is a *Makefile* example that uses double slashes in paths to targets:

```
out/file.txt:
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo aaa > $@

out//file.txt:
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo bbb > $@
```

*make* interprets this as two different targets. If you run `make out/file.txt`, the first rule will be executed. If you run `make out//file.txt`, the second rule will be executed.

Also, if you run `make out///file.txt` and `file.txt` does not exist, you'll get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out///file.txt'
```

However if the file exists, it just says:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `out///file.txt'
```

Also *make* builds targets successfully if you run `make .///out/file.txt` or even `make .////././././././////.///.////out/file.txt`

So, is there any defined behavior how *make* works with paths that are literally different, but point to the same file in the filesystem?

I got from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919) answer, that operating system itself doesn't differ such paths. But for *make* they are different.

The problem originates from the such usage:

```
my_target: $(SOME_DIR)/some_file
```

If `SOME_DIR` already has trailing slash, the code above doesn't work. It expands to something like this: `some_dir//some_file` and the rule for the specific case with double slashes doesn't exist.

How can such problems be avoided? Is there any path canonization means in *make*?

Comment: The main technique is to make sure that people don't slap trailing slashes on path components that will be combined with other components with a slash separating the two — or, at least, being consistent in what's expected.  That's a (relatively painless) discipline in writing the values for the macros.  Other than that, I'm not aware of a way around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is direct workaround for my problem - creating a macro that trims trailing slashes:

```
trslashes = $(if $(filter %/,$(1)),$(call trslashes,$(patsubst %/,%,$(1))),$(1))
```

This macro must be used in every place where double slashes can cause a problem:

```
my_target: $(call trslashes,$(SOME_DIR))/some_file
```

If `$(SOME_DIR)` is empty the file from root directory will be used: 
`/some_file`. If empty variable should mean current directory then another macro should be used:

```
trslashes_cur = $(if $(1),$(call trslashes,$(1)),.)
```

Then `$(call trslashes,$(SOME_DIR))/some_file` will expand to `./somefile`.